# Why does sysout code snippet stop working in VS code after a few seconds?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7tiU.png)

I am trying to use Java in VS code. I am having problems with code completion snippets. I have the Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat extension installed (along with the whole java extension pack), and some of the shorthand doesn't seem to work. prf, private_method, try_catch, and others all work, but not of the System shorthand seems to work: sysout, sout, syserr, etc. When I start up one of my completed projects, sysout works fine, but then after 10 or 15 seconds, the bottom right-hand corner displays "Opening Java Projects: Check details" and sysout no no longer works. It doesn't seem to work at all on new projects or files, even for the first few seconds. I had a bunch of different extensions (including some autocompletion extensions like tabNine) installed previously, but I uninstalled them and VS code, and now I only have the Java extension pack and the Python extension.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the java development kit, the extensions and VS code, restarting and updating my computer, and closing and opening old and new projects.

Comment: well, there's the fact that you're using it in a context where it's not valid code. Why not try it inside a method? I don't get the sysout snippet suggestion when I try to get it outside a method body, but I do get the suggestion inside a method body.

Comment: @starball That seems to be it. Thank you.

Comment: a related issue popped up recently with VS Code 1.80.0 and the Java extension v1.20.0: [Why aren't choice snippets working properly in new files in VS Code 1.80?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76668211/11107541), but it's a much more recent problem that I don't think this is related to.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with there being problems in the previous lines (I'm not sure exactly what the implementation logic is that causes this). Your previous lines have problems because you can't put Java statements outside a method body. If you use the snippets inside a method body with no pre-existing problems, it should work fine.

There seems to be an issue ticket with (very loose) relevance to this here: [Auto complete class methods even in the presence of compilation errors #2922](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2922)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my filename to the first class name and put rest of the code in that class and I was able to use all the snippets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).