# Why aren't choice snippets working properly in new files in VS Code 1.80.0?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

For example, [choice-type snippet suggestions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice) are not showing up as I expect in [version 1.20.0](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/releases/tag/v1.20.0) of the [`redhat.java`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension for VS Code. That includes snippet suggestions and other code suggestions. I observe this every time I create a new file.

In the Java Output log, I see messages like this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core 4 0 2023-07-11 19:09:12.705
!MESSAGE Error occured while building workspace. Details: 
 message: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements; code: 1610612976; resource: <path>.java; line: 6
 message: sout cannot be resolved; code: 570425394; resource: <path>.java; line: 6
 message: Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration; code: 1610612976; resource: <path>.java; line: 6
```

Why is this happening? How can the issue be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a VS Code regression with choice snippets. There's an issue ticket tracking it here: [Are choice snippets dangerous now? Breaking extensions completions #187642](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187642). There was a regression from commit [`3e232a8`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/3e232a82df4313fb8ca898471416763288c6827d). The issue is [reportedly fixed in version 1.80.1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187642#issuecomment-1633749331), which has been released. If it's not available to you yet for some reason, use VS Code Insiders.

The Java extension issue is tracked here: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3194. Notably, if you look in [the release notes for the Red Hat Java Language Support extension, the 1.20.0 section](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200-june-29th-2023) says:

> - enhancement - Use choice syntax as placeholder for constructor/method/field snippets. See [#3018](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/3018), [#3140](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/3140).